# What is the recommended way to propagate panics in tokio tasks?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Right now my panics are being swallowed. In my use case, I would like it to crash entire program and also print the stack trace. How should I configure it?

Answer (score 20):

Panics are generally not swallowed, instead they are returned as an error when awaiting the [`tokio::task::JoinHandle`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html) returned from `tokio::task::spawn()` or `tokio::task::spawn_blocking()` and can be handled accordingly.

If a panic occurs within the Tokio runtime an error message is printed to stderr like this: "thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Panicking...', src\main.rs:26:17". If you run the binary with the environment variable `RUST_BACKTRACE` set to 1 a stacktrace is printed as well.

As with all Rust programs you can set your own panic handler with [`std::panic::set_hook()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html) to make it exit if any thread panics after printing the panic info like this:

```rust
let default_panic = std::panic::take_hook();
std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(move |info| {
    default_panic(info);
    std::process::exit(1);
}));
```

Comment: Exiting just like that is not ideal, in real world scenarios you first need to make sure to shut down or free any reserved resources, connections etc before exiting.